# How to get imageBitmap from external storage using Activity Result API?

Tags: android

I am trying to get image file from external storage using new activity result Api.
My contract always return null from else branch (inside when). Why?

```
class GetImageContract : ActivityResultContract<Unit, Bitmap>() {

    override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Unit?): Intent {
        val intent = Intent(ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        intent.type = "image/*"
        return intent
    }

    override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): Bitmap? {
        return when {
            resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK -> null
            else -> intent?.extras?.get("data") as? Bitmap
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because there is no extra 'data'.

Comment: You better use intent.data.